# 16GB DIMMs in 2010 Mac Pro

Tags: mac, memory

I have a Mac Pro running dual Xeon X5675s (3.06 Ghz). I purchased 8 16GB PC3L-8500R DIMMs in the hope of upgrading it to 128GB. It sees all the memory, but it's only running it at 800 Mhz (PC3-8500 should run at 1066 Mhz). Is this a limitation of the amount of memory, or is it something about these DIMMMs that it doesn't like? I tried another CPU card (also with X5675s) and got the same result. With the original 4GB DIMMs, it runs at the expected speed.

ETA: I'm answering my own question. This is apparently a weakness of the architecture. If I remove the fourth DIMM from each bank, the memory runs at the correct speed.

Comment: The "L" in PC3L indicates a low voltage spec for RAM. It is usually supported without any problems, but perhaps the presence of this type of RAM results in odd behavior. Just a guess, mind you.

Comment: it can run 64GB as dual channel [8's] or 96GB as triple [16s].

Answer (score 3):

It can run 64GB as dual channel [8's] or 96GB as triple [16s].

From EveryMac - [Silver-Colored Mac Pro Q&A](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/faq/mac-pro-mid-2010-westmere-how-to-upgrade-memory.html)

> **Actual Maximum RAM**
>
> Although "Mid-2010" and "Mid-2012" Mac Pro systems with a single
>   processor, which EveryMac.com notes as the "Quad Core" and "Six Core"
>   models, officially support a maximum of 16 GB of RAM, as discovered by
>   site sponsor Other World Computing, they actually can support more.
>   OWC first noted an actual maximum of 32 GB of RAM and later increased
>   this actual maximum to 48 GB of RAM.
>
> Systems with dual processors, which EveryMac.com notes as the "Eight
>   Core" and "Twelve Core" models, likewise officially support 32 GB of
>   RAM, but again, OWC found they actually can support more. OWC first
>   confirmed an actual maximum of 64 GB of RAM running Mac OS X 10.5
>   "Leopard" and later increased this maximum to 96 GB of RAM running Mac
>   OS X 10.6 "Snow Leopard" or higher. More recently, OWC yet again
>   discovered these dual processor models can support up to 128 GB, but
>   only when running a 64-bit version of Windows XP or later or Linux.
>   Mac OS X only can support 96 GB of RAM.

Comment: That information is our of date. Later versions of OSX and MacOS support the full 128GB

Comment: & yet appears borne out by your own tests. I cannot test for myself, I have 8x8 in mine, which works as expected.

Comment: No, I am able to access the full 128GB, just at a reduced speed. That would be a hardware, not software issue.